# How to add clickListener to children of nested recyclerViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I am trying to develop an e-reader app. I have implemented nested recyclerviews to get desired design, which looks like:

[image]

I want to implement clickListeners to this design such that if the title of the section (ex:"Category 1") or the arrow button in front of it is clicked then it sends the user to an activity showing books of that category.
And if the item of child recycler view, the book cover, it's title or anything in that card layout is clicked then the user is sent to an activity showing description of that book and other options like read, add to library etc.
How do I achieve that?

My code is:

Book:

```
public class Book {
    private int uniqueId;
    private String bookTitle;
    private String bookAuthor;
//    private String bookCoverImageURL;
    private int readPercentage;
    private int views;
    private int bookCoverImage;
    private String bookSummary;
    private String publishedDate;
    private String readingTime;

    public Book(int bookCoverImage, String bookTitle, String readingTime, int views) {
        this.bookCoverImage = bookCoverImage;
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.readingTime =readingTime;
        this.views= views;
    }

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    public String getBookAuthor() {
        return bookAuthor;
    }

//    public String getBookCoverImageURL() {
////        return bookCoverImageURL;
////    }

    public int getReadPercentage() {
        return readPercentage;
    }

    public int getBookCoverImage() {
        return bookCoverImage;
    }

    public int getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public String getBookSummary() {
        return bookSummary;
    }
    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public String getReadingTime() {
        return readingTime;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(int uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    }

    public void setReadPercentage(int readPercentage) {
        this.readPercentage = readPercentage;
    }

    public void setBookCoverImage(int bookCoverImage) {
        this.bookCoverImage = bookCoverImage;
    }

    public void setBookSummary(String bookSummary) {
        this.bookSummary = bookSummary;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }


    public void setReadingTime(String readingTime) {
        this.readingTime = readingTime;
    }
}
```

CategorySection:

```
public class CategorySection {
    private String categoryTitle;
    private ArrayList<Book> mBookList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getCategoryTitle() {
        return categoryTitle;
    }

    public void setCategoryTitle(String categoryTitle) {
        this.categoryTitle = categoryTitle;
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> getmBookList() {
        return mBookList;
    }

    public void setmBookList(ArrayList<Book> mBookList) {
        this.mBookList = mBookList;
    }
```

HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter:

```
public class HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter.BookViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Book> mBookList = new ArrayList<>();


    public HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Book> mBookList) {
        this.mBookList = mBookList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_category_section_book_card, parent, false);
        return new BookViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Book currentBook = mBookList.get(position);
        String title = currentBook.getBookTitle();
        String readTime = currentBook.getReadingTime();
        int nofviews = currentBook.getViews();


        holder.bookCoverImage.setImageResource(currentBook.getBookCoverImage());
        holder.bookTitle.setText(title);
        holder.readingTime.setText(readTime);
        holder.views.setText(nofviews+" views");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBookList.size();
    }

    public class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView bookCoverImage;
        public TextView bookTitle;
        public TextView readingTime;
        public TextView views;

        public BookViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bookCoverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_image_view);
            bookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_title);
            readingTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_reading_time);
            views = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_views);


        }
    }
}
```

HomeCategorySectionAdapter:

```
public class HomeCategorySectionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCategorySectionsAdapter.CategorySectionViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<CategorySection> mSectionList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

    public HomeCategorySectionsAdapter(ArrayList<CategorySection> mSectionList) {
        this.mSectionList = mSectionList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategorySectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_category_section_card, parent, false);
        return new CategorySectionViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategorySectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CategorySection currentSection = mSectionList.get(position);
        String sectionTitle = currentSection.getCategoryTitle();
        holder.categoryTitle.setText(sectionTitle);


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(holder.booksRecyclerView.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(currentSection.getmBookList().size());

        HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter booksAdapter = new HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter(mSectionList.get(position).getmBookList());
        holder.booksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        holder.booksRecyclerView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
        holder.booksRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSectionList.size();
    }

    public class CategorySectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView categoryTitle;
        public RecyclerView booksRecyclerView;

        public CategorySectionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_category_section_title);
            booksRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_category_section_books_recyclerview);
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_sections_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        HomeCategorySectionsAdapter sectionsAdapter = new HomeCategorySectionsAdapter(buildSectionList());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionsAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private ArrayList<CategorySection> buildSectionList() {
        ArrayList<CategorySection> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            CategorySection categorySection = new CategorySection();
            categorySection.setCategoryTitle("Category "+(i+1));
            categorySection.setmBookList(buildBookList());
            sectionList.add(categorySection);
        }
        return sectionList;
    }

    private ArrayList<Book> buildBookList() {
        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
            Book book = new Book(R.drawable.the_poppy_wife,"Title "+(i+1),(10+1)+" minutes",i*10+2*i);
            bookList.add(book);
        }

        return bookList;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive click event of child in parent by sharing reference of parent adapter in child adapter class.
you can also get parent and child adapter click event in fragment. You need to pass reference :

**HomeFragment change**

**new HomeCategorySectionsAdapter(this, buildSectionList());**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_sections_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    HomeCategorySectionsAdapter sectionsAdapter = new HomeCategorySectionsAdapter(this, buildSectionList());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionsAdapter);

    return view;
}

private ArrayList<CategorySection> buildSectionList() {
    ArrayList<CategorySection> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        CategorySection categorySection = new CategorySection();
        categorySection.setCategoryTitle("Category "+(i+1));
        categorySection.setmBookList(buildBookList());
        sectionList.add(categorySection);
    }
    return sectionList;
}

private ArrayList<Book> buildBookList() {
    ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        Book book = new Book(R.drawable.the_poppy_wife,"Title "+(i+1),(10+1)+" minutes",i*10+2*i);
        bookList.add(book);
    }

    return bookList;
}
   public void childObserver(String message){
Log.d("TAG","receive message from child adapter");
    }
}
```

**In HomeCategorySectionAdapter change constructor**

**And add a public function in which child adapter click event receive.
Also pass fragment and parent adapter reference in child adapter.**

```
public class HomeCategorySectionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCategorySectionsAdapter.CategorySectionViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;
private ArrayList<CategorySection> mSectionList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

public HomeCategorySectionsAdapter(HomeFragment homeFragment, ArrayList<CategorySection> mSectionList) {
    this.mSectionList = mSectionList;
    this.mHomeFragment = homeFragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategorySectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_category_section_card, parent, false);
    return new CategorySectionViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategorySectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CategorySection currentSection = mSectionList.get(position);
    String sectionTitle = currentSection.getCategoryTitle();
    holder.categoryTitle.setText(sectionTitle);


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(holder.booksRecyclerView.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(currentSection.getmBookList().size());

    HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter booksAdapter = new HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter(this,mHomeFragmnet,  mSectionList.get(position).getmBookList());
    holder.booksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    holder.booksRecyclerView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);
    holder.booksRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSectionList.size();
}

public class CategorySectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView categoryTitle;
    public RecyclerView booksRecyclerView;

    public CategorySectionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_category_section_title);
        booksRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_category_section_books_recyclerview);
    }
}
 public void childAdapterObserver(String message){
  Log.d("TAG","child click event   "+message)
  }

}
```

**In HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter adapter**

```
public class HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter.BookViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Book> mBookList = new ArrayList<>();
private HomeCategorySectionsAdapter mParentAdapter;
private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;



public HomeCategorySectionBooksAdapter(HomeCategorySectionsAdapter parentAdapter, HomeFragment homeFragment, ArrayList<Book> mBookList) {
    this.mBookList = mBookList;
    this.mParentAdapter= parentAdapter;
    this.mHomeFragment= homeFragment;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_category_section_book_card, parent, false);
    return new BookViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Book currentBook = mBookList.get(position);
    String title = currentBook.getBookTitle();
    String readTime = currentBook.getReadingTime();
    int nofviews = currentBook.getViews();


    holder.bookCoverImage.setImageResource(currentBook.getBookCoverImage());
    holder.bookTitle.setText(title);
    holder.readingTime.setText(readTime);
    holder.views.setText(nofviews+" views");

    holder.views.setOnClickListener->{
     mHomeFragment.childObserver("viewClick");
          mParentAdapter.childAdapterObserver("viewClick");
   }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mBookList.size();
}

public class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView bookCoverImage;
    public TextView bookTitle;
    public TextView readingTime;
    public TextView views;

    public BookViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bookCoverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_image_view);
        bookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_title);
        readingTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_reading_time);
        views = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card_book_views);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened, there were no debug messages on clicking any child item

Comment: yes, I implemented the whole updated code, applied every change